# Ubuntu fork bomb handling. Fork: Resource temporarily unavailable. Is it not a threat any more?

Tags: security

I've ran across a discussion of Linux security. A fork bomb was suggested as a way to freeze OS. It supposed to prevent other processes from running. I've tried this command (DO NOT TRY IT UNLESS YOU ARE READY FOR FREEZES!) “:(){ :|: & };:”

But all I got is Fork: Resource temporarily unavailable.

Task manager started without a problem, so did the browser. Seems like Ubuntu is reaching the cgroup limit.

Does it mean that fork bomb is not a threat since some version of Ubuntu OR it needs a lot of components + root access OR just a couple of instructions might make it dangerous again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

Todays computers have a lot more memory and processing powers. That means there's a bigger chance that you'll run into the limits before exhausting RAM today than ten years ago.

In addition, you can, if you want to protect against this, set up [limits](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23533/how-to-protect-ubuntu-from-fork-bomb) on how many processes a user can run.

All in all this is most relevant on a multi user system. On a single user desktop, a fork bomb is not a disaster anyway. Worst case? Reboot.